# How to run a function in a List of a List in python

Tags: python-3.x

Pins.txt (IIIIIIIIII)

```
def remove_pins(s,e,file_name):   
   file = open(file_name, "r")   
   pins = file.readline() #only one line    
   file.close()   
   d = e -s    
   new_pins = pins[:s] + "."* (d+1) + pins[e+1:]   
   return new_pins
```

I have to create a function called # def bowling(balls):

FILL-IN: return a string with the pins that are still standing or knocked down after the turns.

For example,

```
ball_sequences = [[0,1],[4,5]]
```

`bowling (ball_sequences)` returns “..II..IIII”

Comment: The file is pins.txt which only contains IIIIIIIIII

Comment: Thanks for sharing _YOUR_ task with us. How do you intend to solve it? We dont. If you have a specific problem, post your solution, explain the shortcomings and we might help. We dont code your homework for you because we can not learn for you, you got to do that on your own.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you want to write a function that takes a list of ranges to remove instead of just removing one range at a time like `remove_pins`. So you would have something like this:

```
def bowling(rangeList,file_name):   
    file = open(file_name, "r")   
    pins = file.readline()   
    file.close()
    for rang in rangeList:
        d = e -s    
        pins = pins[:rang[0]] + "."* (d+1) + pins[rang[1]+1:]   
    return pins
```